# how do i edit a masterpage div from child page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, htmlcontrols

what's the DIV equivalent to this command?

```
((Panel)this.Page.Master.FindControl("Panel1")).Style.Add("display", "none");
```

This works great with a panel but I can't find the variation for doing the same thing with a DIV who's ID I know. anyone know?

thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 10):

Div belongs to HtmlGenericControl class of System.Web.UI.HtmlControls namespace.

```
((HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("divID")).Style.Add("display", "none");
```

and your your div control in master page sholud be `runat="server"`

Thanks

Asif

Answer (score 2):

If the div is `runat="server"`, it is an `HttpGenericControl` rather than a `Panel`. If the div is not `runat="server"`, you cannot access it server-side like you would a WebControl.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this from the server-side code (code-behind), then you just have to add the `runat="server"` attribute to the DIV:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server">...</div>
```

Then you access the div the same way as the panel in your example.